# discordpy on_message missing argument

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if '$hello' in message.content:
        await ctx.send('Hello!')
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itama\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to make it so if when I type "hello" it reponds "Hello!"

Comment: My guess: Probably you have to provide the `context`. Your "hello" goes as the first argument. To get a real answer you have to provide much more context for that question, e.g. show how you execute it etc. Anyway, hello on SO :)

Comment: Thanks and it's working now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` only takes one argument - `message`

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return # Exiting if it's ourselves

    if "$hello" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

Only commands take `ctx`

Comment: then how i can send the message? await client.send('Hello!')?

Comment: `message.channel.send`

Comment: TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Comment: @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '$hello' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

Comment: That works, I copied it and it works fine for me, you're doing something wrong

Comment: you should check if the user that send the message is not the bot, check the edit

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped